# QGIS export vector PDF/SVG and import to Scribus: suspect map frame size

Tags: export, print-composer, pdf, svg, scribus

I would like to prepress my maps in Scribus (I need to convert them in to CMYK-Colorspace for my printing agency). So I need to export my maps as vector file from QGIS and import it into Scribus. So far so good. The vectors and labels are imported very well but the map size and the map frame has changed. You can see it in the second screen shot:

The red *outside* frame is my DIN A4 page from Scribus, the other red frame (selecting frame) is that one of my imported qgis-map. The black frame is my final map. It's scaled. But why? I think it could have something to do with the masking...

(Importing into Inkscape works well, but the "inkscape-reexport" behaves like the qgis-pdf.)

[image: Print-Composer Export Setting]

[image: Result in Scribus]

**EDIT:** I found out, that it makes a difference, how you import the PDF into Scribus. If you use `File -> Import -> Get Vector File...` or use drag and drop, the result will be like I described, but if you use  `right click -> Paste File` the imported PDF will placed in it's original size and borders. For me its enough to go further...

Answer (score 3):

On the one side, Scribus is not a tool for converting between color spaces.
But, of course, you can *abuse it* for this task.

This having been said, the SVG import is steadily being improved and we need samples of failing SVGs to catch the corner cases.

Since you seem to be using the latest version of Scribus, you're very welcome to upload the original SVG from QGIS and the screenshots showing the issues to the [Scribus Bug Tracker](https://bugs.scribus.net).

We already have samples of failing exports from OpenStreetMap: SVG maps  that are automatically generated seem to be tough.
(Their authors seem to be lazy and refrain from *cutting* the map at its boundaries. By hiding the overflowing parts they make their task easier, but harder for Scribus.)

Finally, keep in mind that Scribus:

- only implements the SVG features that can (easily) be translated to PDF.
- in Scribus, SVGs are translated to a group of *native* vector items and masks might be hard to translate.

And, of course, for the time being, you can always export a PNG or TIFF from QGIS/Inkscape and get Scribus (or another tool) to convert it to CMYK in the PDF.